# Omega footer navigation

Tags: 7, routes, theming, navigation

I'm making a footer menu. The base-theme I use is Omega. Now I'm looking for the best way to add a CSS value to each menu-item, so Omega places them next to eachother.

Basicaly, what I would like to do is adding "grid-3" to the parent menu items...
In the example you can see class="nolink" (from the module special_menu_items), I also want to add the class "grid-3".

```
<li class="first expanded"><span title="" class="nolink">Web Design</span>
  <ul class="menu">
  <li class="first leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">Drupal Design</a></li>
  <li class="leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">Graphic Design</a></li>
  <li class="last leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">Logo Design</a></li>
  </ul></li>
  <li class="expanded"><span title="" class="nolink">SEO Services</span><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">Google Adwords</a></li>
  <li class="leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">Great Keywords</a></li>
  <li class="leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">Link Submission</a></li>
  <li class="last leaf"><a href="/geek.screamingsilence.be/" title="" class="active">SEO Link Building</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use hook_menu_link_HOOK

For example if your menu is the main menu you could use this example code in your template.php to add class to tag li.

```
function YOUTHEME_menu_link__main_menu(array $variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = ''; 
  /* add classes to balise li */
  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'grid-3';
  /*$element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'depth-' . $element['#original_link']['depth'];*/
  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $title = $element['#title'];

  $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['id'] = $title ;

  $output = l($lien, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . "</li>\n";

}
```

To add the class only to the parent menu, you should use a condition to see if the menu item has children. Or make a condition to see if the tag li has the class depth-1 and then add the class grid-3.

The module [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) seems to do the job too.

Comment: Hmm, seems nice, can I use this hook with a custom menu also? The name of the menu is "footer menu", so YOUTHEME_menu_link__footer_menu should work?

Comment: yes, it's the syntax. You have to look at the machine name of your menu. If it's footer-menu, then use YOUTHEME_menu_link__footer_menu. Let me know if you succeed and with wich condition.

Comment: the system name of "footer menu" seems to be "menu_footer_menu", it's working :)